# InvokeHTTP processor issue

Tags: apache-nifi

Facing an issue with 'InvokeHTTP' NiFi processor.

Have configured below URL for GET operation -

https://1.186.47.226:8541/webacs/api/v3/data/WlanControllerDetails.json

When I run the processor I got this error that I have attached screenshot below.

Please, suggest me how to resolve the issue.

Thank You

[image]

Comment: probably the certificate is invalid. could you call this url from browser?

Comment: Please share the configuration of your `InvokeHTTP` processor and any `SSLContextService` that you have referenced there.